# Calculating the probability of reaching each absorbing state in Markov Chain

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I'm starting with a Matrix that looks like this:

```
[[ 0 , 1/2, 0,  0 ,  0 , 1/2], 
 [4/9,  0 , 0, 3/9, 2/9,  0 ], 
 [ 0 ,  0 , 1,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ], 
 [ 0 ,  0 , 0,  1 ,  0 ,  0 ], 
 [ 0 ,  0 , 0,  0 ,  1 ,  0 ], 
 [ 0 ,  0 , 0,  0 ,  0 ,  1 ]]
```

And I'm being asked to calculate the probability of reaching each of the absorbing states C, D, E, and F starting from A. Obviously C is 0, and the other probabilities are given as:

A to D -> 3/14

A to E -> 1/7

A to F -> 9/14

but I don't know what steps or formulas I need to arrive at those values.
I don't really know where to start with this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Absorbing_probabilities)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The state transition diagram for the given problem is given by:

[image]

Consider transitions from A to D:

It could happen in several ways, as listed in the following. All these paths are mutually exclusive. Invoking the definition of of first passage time, we can obtain the required probability.

\begin{eqnarray*}
A\rightarrow B \rightarrow D &=& p_{AB}\cdot p_{BD}\\
&=&\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{3}{9}\right)=\frac{3}{18}\\
A\rightarrow B\rightarrow  A\rightarrow B  \rightarrow D &=& p_{AB}\cdot p_{BA}\cdot p_{AB}\cdot  p_{BD}\\
&=&\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{3}{9}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)\left(\frac{3}{9}\right)\\
A\rightarrow B\rightarrow  A\rightarrow B\rightarrow  A\rightarrow B   \rightarrow D &=& p_{AB}\cdot p_{BA}\cdot p_{AB}\cdot p_{BA}\cdot p_{AB}\cdot  p_{BD}=p_{AB}\cdot \left(p_{BA}p_{AB}\right)^{2}\cdot  p_{BD}\\
&=&\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{3}{9}\right)\\
\end{eqnarray*}
and several more such transitions. The probability of ever reaching from state A to D is obtained from the following probability:

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\frac{3}{18}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)\left(\frac{3}{9}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{3}{9}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^{3}\left(\frac{3}{9}\right)+\cdots\\
&=&\frac{3}{18}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)\left(\frac{3}{9}\right)\left\{1+\frac{2}{9}+\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^{2}+\cdots\right\}\\
&=&\frac{3}{18}+\frac{1}{3\times 9}\left\{\dfrac{1}{1-2/9}\right\}=\frac{27}{126}=\frac{3}{14}
\end{eqnarray*}
In a similar manner, we can find other probabilities.

Comment: Isn't there also something that has to do with finding the fundamental matrix and summing each of the rows? I I'm not sure how to mathematicall formalize that.

Comment: You are right.  It is an iterative procedure. $F^{(n-1)}=P(F^{(n)}-F_{d}^{(n)})$, where $F^{(n)}=(f_{ij}^{(n)})$ and $F_{d}^{(n)}$ is diagonal matrix whose entries are the diagonal entries of $F^{(n)}$, and $F^{(1)}=P$.

Comment: There was a typo in the above equation. The iterative equation should read as $F^{(n+1)}=P(F^{(n)}-F_{d}^{(n)})$,

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how you got from the 2nd step to the 3rd step in the solution.

Comment: Look at the state transition diagram. We want the probability that the process moves from state  A to State D for the first time. This could happen in several mutually exclusive ways. The first one is one path that process may take to go from A to D. The second one another path, and so on. Sum of the probabilities of all such transitions is the required probability.

Comment: Each one is a different path from State A to State D. Simplest is $A\rightarrow B \rightarrow D$. Or having started in state A, the process may move to state B, come back to A, then go to B and finally from B to D. This movement of B to A and A to B may get repeated  several times.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to mathematical software like Python, you can solve it using the following trick.

The Eigendecomposition lets us split the matrix into

V x D x  V^-1 where V is the eigenvector, and d is the eigenvalues.

the terminal states are then V x D ^ inf x V^-1, and we can find D ^ inf by looking at whether the values are >= or < 1.

Here is code that solves your problem.

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array(
    [
    [0, 1 / 2, 0, 0, 0, 1 / 2],
    [4 / 9, 0, 0, 3 / 9, 2 / 9, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    ]
)
d, v = np.linalg.eig(m)
v @ np.diag(d >= 1).astype(int) @ np.linalg.inv(v) 


[[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.21428571, 0.14285714, 0.64285714],

   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.42857143, 0.28571429,   0.28571429],

   [0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,  0.        ],

   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,  0.        ],

   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ,    0.       ],

   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,1.        ]]
```